# Pre-select items on data-bound cascading dropdown lists in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have the following problem:

On a ASP.NET page, say books.aspx, I have three dropdown lists: *ddlBook*, *ddlChapter*, *ddlPage*, one listview *lvPageContents* and four sql datasources *dsBooks*, *dsChapters*, *dsPages* and *dsPageContents*.

On initial design, user selects the Book from *ddlBook* (populated from *dsBook*), then Chapter (from the selected book's chapters) and Page (from the selected chapter's pages). Finally, the lvPageContents shows the data of the selected page.

I would like to add the functionality of calling books.aspx with *QueryString("BookID")* or "ChapterID" or "PageID" and programmatically put the corresponding values as selected items to the corresponding dropdown lists.

Should I completely override the datasource/databinding of ASP.NET in code behind, or is there another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In code behind .cs file you can pre select  Drop down list using Item Lists index.

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

or by using values like this-

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "page1";
```